# How to make this typescript work in ConTeXt?

Tags: fonts, context

I'm trying to come to grips with typescripts in ConTeXt. Amongst all the examples and all the documentation, it just is not clear what is happening.

I downloaded a new font for use with this example [here](http://www.fontspace.com/gluk/kleymissky). It's called *kleymissky* and the output of `mtxrun --script fonts --info` is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b969b354e423d508b9d3).

My test file is as follows:

```
\starttypescript[serif][kleymissky]
    \setups[font:fallback:serif]
    \definefontsynonym[Serif][name:kleymissky][features=default]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [myfont]
    \definetypeface[myfont][rm][serif][kleymissky][default]
    \definetypeface[myfont][ss][sans][modern][default]
    \definetypeface[myfont][tt][mono][modern][default]
\stoptypescript

\usebodyfont[myfont]

\starttext
{\tf This is tf.} 
{\ss This is ss.} 
{\tt This is tt.} 
{\definedfont[name:kleymissky] This is kleymissky.}
{\definedfont[name:modern] This is latin-modern.}
\stoptext
```

The intent is to use kleymissky for the main serif font, but to revert to the Latin Modern font for ss and tt. But that is not the behavior:

[image: output2]

For comparison, I tried the `simplefonts` module, which ended up doing what I wanted:

```
\usemodule   [simplefonts]
\setmainfont [kleymissky]

\starttext
{\tf This is tf.}
{\ss This is ss.}
{\tt This is tt.}
{\definedfont[name:kleymissky] This is kleymissky.}
{\definedfont[name:modern] This is latin-modern.}
\stoptext
```

and I get:

[image: output3]

So obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot fathom what. Could someone help me to fix this typescript and/or help me to understand what is happening?

Comment: Use `\setupbodyfont[myfont]` to load the fonts from your typescript.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the `\usebodyfont[myfont]` line in your example with `\setupbodyfont[myfont]` to enable your typeface.

A alternative to the `simplefonts` module is the `\definefontfamily` command from the core which allows you to use fonts without the need to write a typescript.

```
\definefontfamily [kleymissky] [rm] [Kleymissky]
\definefontfamily [kleymissky] [ss] [Latin Modern Sans]
\definefontfamily [kleymissky] [tt] [Latin Modern Mono] [features=none]
\definefontfamily [kleymissky] [mm] [Latin Modern Math]

\setupbodyfont[kleymissky]

\starttext

This is rm.

{\ss This is ss.}

{\tt This is tt.}

\stoptext
```